# Highstock breaks at 140 points

Tags: highcharts

I've got a working Highstock graph that breaks with a data series of about 140 points. I know Highstock can take over 50,000 points so I'm not sure what is happening with mine.

The JSON is fine. I tested it line by line and watched the chart break around the 140th entry.

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('stock2.json', function(data) {
    $('#container1').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1,
            inputEnabled : $('#container').width() > 480
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Turnover and Spread Comparison with TSE for N225'
        },
        yAxis : [{
            title : {
                text :'Spread (BPS)'
            },
            opposite : false,
        },
        {
            title : {
                text :'Average Daily Turnover (Billion JPY)'
            },
        }],
        legend : {
            enabled : true,
            floating : true,
            align : 'left',
            shadow : true,
            layout : 'vertical',
            x : 100,
            y : -332,
            borderWidth : 2,
            borderColor : '#8BCAFF',
            backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
        },
        colors : ['#8BCAFF','#BC0000', '#030060', '#BC0000', '#030060' ], // Line colours
        series : [{
            name : 'Turnover',
            data : data.d1,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 10, 4),
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 7,
            type : 'column',
            yAxis : 1,
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2,
                valueSuffix : ' JPY'
            }
        }]
    });
});
});
```

Comment: How your json does it look like? Have you any errors in the console?

Comment: The JSON file is fine as long as I keep the number of points limited to about 140. Console shows zero errors. Everything gets loaded.

Comment: Could you attach that JSON example?

Comment: Figured it out. 
Turns out there is a bug relating to floating legends in either Chrome for linux or CentOS6.